# undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state.params

Tags: react-native, navigation, navigator

I have a parent and child, I am using navigator to route between them, I have some state in the child component and I want to pass the state value in that component to the parent without routing the parent.

so far I have the code as follow:
on my parent:

```
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Riddles', {
              onChangeCount: this.onChangeCount.bind(this)
            })}
        >
```

as you can see on my parent (which is the home screen) I have butten that onPress navigate to Riddles screen (which is my child component)

on the child component I setup as follow:

```
 nextQuestion() {
    this.setState({
      userAnswer: '',
      count: this.state.count + 1,
      diamonds: this.state.diamonds + 5
    })
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
    this.props.navigation.state.params.onChangeCount(1)
    this.refs.modalCorrect.close()
    this.saveData()
  }
```

and render it (on child - riddles screen ):

```
return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.modalButtonAnswer}
            onPress={() => this.nextQuestion()}
          >
```

as much as I understod, the line " this.props.navigation.state.params.onChangeCount(1)" send the value "1" to  my parent screen and in the parend screen I need to bind this (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1416)
, but it doesn't work for me, please help....

Comment: Is the child component getting the appropriate navigation via props? You haven't posted your StackNavigator related code so try and see what's inside navigate ( console.log(navigate) ) after your destructuring assignment.

Comment: this is my StackNavigator:const Navigate = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Riddles: { screen: RiddlesScreen },
    Introduction: { screen: IntroductionScreen },
    About: { screen: AboutScreen },
  },
  { headerMode: 'screen' },
);